# Starting GlassFish 3.1 at localhost has encountered a problem "domain setup not complete"

Tags: eclipse, glassfish

I get this error when I start GlassFish 3.1 in Eclipse. How to fix it?
I Googled but don't see anything related to it.

Comment: Has it worked ever? I got a similar error after doing some windows updates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This makes no sense to me, but I backed out and got an error about how glassfish needs a JDK, not a JRE - I went in via Windows->Prefs->Servers and edited the Glassfish entry and set it to JDK and now it works.